# Difference between two mixins in SASS

Tags: sass

**Mixin 1**

```
$prefixes: ("-webkit-","-moz-", "-o-", "-ms-", "");

@mixin prefix($property, $value) {
  @each $prefix in $prefixes {
    #{$prefix}#{$property}: #{$value};
  }
}
```

**Mixin 2**

```
// Vendor prefix
@mixin prefix($property, $value) {
  -webkit-#{$property}: $value;
  -moz-#{$property}: $value;
  -ms-#{$property}: $value;
  -o-#{$property}: $value;
  #{$property}: $value;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in `mixin 2`. The `mixin 1` works perfectly, but it seems the `mixin 2` has some problem. Both does the same.

Comment: mixin2 should work fine as it is, there does not seem to be anything wrong with it. It sure does on it's own: [**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/11559325), so it might be some kind of conflict when you are using it with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
   @mixin prefix($property, $value) {
      -webkit-#{$property}: #{$value};
      -moz-#{$property}: #{$value};
      -ms-#{$property}: #{$value};
      -o-#{$property}: #{$value};
      #{$property}: #{$value};
    }
```

Hope I help